# Kkilling form $\kappa(t_\alpha , t_\alpha ) \neq 0$ for a root $\alpha$ of semisimple lie algebra $L$

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

$L$ is a semisimple lie algebra and $H$ is the maximal toral subalgebra. Then the killing form $\kappa$ restricting to $H$ is non degenerated. Therefore we can associate $\varphi \in H^*$ with $t_\varphi \in H$ s.t. $\varphi(*) = \kappa (t_\varphi , *)$ .

For a root $\alpha \neq 0$, we have $t_\alpha$ such that $\kappa (t_\alpha , *) = \alpha$. Then how to show that $\kappa( t_\alpha , t_\alpha) \neq 0$?

A probably accessible way is like this. Since $t_\alpha \in H$, it is ad-semisimple. If we can show that $t_\alpha$ is ad-nilpotent. Then $\mathrm(ad )_L t_\alpha = 0$ and $t_\alpha \in Z(L)$ which contradicts the fact that $L$ is semisimple.

Comment: Crossposted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344282/killing-form-kappat-alpha-t-alpha-neq-0-for-a-root-alpha-of-semisi).

Comment: Your comment on MO: "*He (Humphrey §8.3) said  is solvable then $\mathrm{ad}_L()$ is nilpotent for $s\in [S,S]$. However, we can only say that $\mathrm{ad}_S(s)$ or $\mathrm{ad}_{\mathrm{ad}_S}\mathrm{ad}_S=0$.*"

Comment: Humphreys's argument seems correct. If $L$ is a (finite-dimensional char 0) Lie algebra and $S$ is a solvable subalgebra, then it follows from the Lie-Kolchin theorem that for every $s\in [S,S]$, we have $\mathrm{ad}_L(s)$ is nilpotent. Indeed it's true for every finite-dimensional representation of $S$, not only the adjoint representation of its over-algebra $L$.